# How to find the value of a selected object using onSelect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function onSelect which allows me to check what option from my menu has been selected by a user. I want to iterate through that value of what is selected by the user to display the items associated with that option. How can I find value of what is selected by the user? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import './horizontalscroll.css';
import Items from './items';

// list of items




// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="menu-item"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};




// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list) => list.map(el => {
  const { name } = el;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      text={name}
      key={name}

    />
  );
});


const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
    >{text}</div>
  );
};


const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {

  state = {
    selected: 0,
    statelist: [
  {name: "Brands",
    items: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {name: "Films",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  },
  {name: "Holiday Destination",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
]

  };



  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });



  }


  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(this.state.statelist, selected);
    const {statelist} = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />

      <Items Items={Items[selected]}/>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

Comment: What are you getting in `onSelect` method presently?

Comment: Sorry i do not understand what you mean?

Comment: ```onSelect``` is saving what is being selected  on the menu. I want to find the value of what is selected

Comment: In `onSelect` method, you should be getting the item key.  On the basis of that key you should be able to find the other details of the items, if I'm getting it correctly.

Comment: `const myDetails = list.filter(i=>i.key == key);` in your `onSelect` should give you the details.

Comment: Also, I see a problem with `selected: 0` Shouldn't it be something like `selected: 'Brands'` just saying on the basis of this documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu

Answer (score 1):

```
 onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });

    const myList = this.state.statelist;
    const myItemDetails = myList.filter(i=>i.key === key); // The details that you want

  }
```